# サーバー上のファイルが開けない

Tags: emeditor

会社のファイルサーバーにVPN接続をし、ファイルサーバー上からemeditorでファイルを開こうとすると開けなくなりました。(6/18時点では問題なし）。
同じファイルを、ローカルにコピーするとemeditorで問題なく開けます。
またサーバー上のファイルを、別のアプリ（メモ帳や秀丸など）で開いても問題なく開けます。
解決策がありましたらご教示ください。

補足：開けない→該当ファイルがないとアラートが出ます。
ファイル形式は　.txtです。

Comment: 問題が発生した前後で、どのような環境の違いがありますか? たとえば、EmEditor のバージョンや設定が変わっているのでしょうか?

Comment: Yutakaさま
emaditor自体の変更は変わっていません。
ただ、社内のネットワーク環境の切り替えはありました（IPアドレスは変更なし）
ネットワークすべてのファイルが見えないのであれば、社内ネットワークを疑うのですが、ファイルはみえて（ファイルがあることは確認できる）いるのにemeditorでは開けない、という現象です。
ネットワークとの関連付けのような設定があったのでしょうか…。

Comment: [カスタマイズ] ダイアログの [ファイル] タブで、ファイル アクセス タイムアウトは、何秒に設定していますか? 問題のパスは、ドライブ名 (`Z:`など) が割り当てられていいるのでしょうか? UNCパス (`\\server\share\...`のようなパス) で指定してみてはいかがでしょうか? また、エラーが発生している画面図を見せていただけますか?

Comment: Yutakaさま
ありがとうございます。ネットワークの方を疑い色々試してみたのですが、結局WindowsUpdateのせいだったようで
https://chroco-design.com/blog.php?id=140
こちらの方法で解決したようです（現状では）
なぜEmeditorだけ弾かれたのかわからないのですが、様子をみたいと思います。